# Python3 BFS Flood Fill with Deque and 2D Indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathfinding

I'm currently in a programming competition where time is key, therefore I'm trying to optimize my solution as much as possible. I am trying to implement a BFS Flood Fill solution on a map size of 30x30 (900 operations) where the time limit is 1 second. I'm falling a bit short on time (a little bit above 1 second). I changed all my lists into a deque (for speed) and I changed my 1D list into a 2D list for faster indexing. I'm trying to calculate the distance for each node to every other node so that I can just look it up later on.

What else can I try to get a bit of speed?

Here is my BFS Function:

```
def BFS5(grid, start):
    visited = deque([])
    for _ in range(height):
        visited.append(deque([-1]*width))

    queue = deque([start])
    _x, _y = start.x, start.y
    visited[_y][_x] = 0
    distance = 1
    while queue:
        current_point = queue.popleft()
        if grid[current_point.y][current_point.x] == -1:
            continue

        adjacent_points = current_point.get_adjacents(grid)
        for point in adjacent_points:
            if grid[point.y][point.x] == -1:
                continue
            if visited[point.y][point.x] >= 0:
                continue
            _x, _y = point.x, point.y
            visited[_y][_x] = distance
            queue.append(point)
            distance += 1
    return visited
```

Grid example:

```
[
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1],
    [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
]
```

Comment: can you include an example grid?

Comment: @MaartenFabré added to original question